# Access to S3 object but not bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, s3cmd

I have been given full access to an S3 folder by means of an ACL. However, when I try to list the objects in that folder I get an

ERROR: Access to bucket '[bucket name]' was denied

I do not have access to the bucket. I was only given access to the folder. Ultimately I need to see the files in this folder and to run an EMR job on them.

Comment: ACLs only apply to buckets and objects -- not "folders," which don't actually exist in S3.  The S3 analog to folders is prefixes, which can be used in policies... not ACLs.  Either I am missing something or it's not really an ACL or whoever set this up did not test their provisioning to see if it actually works.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

A good explanation of granting access to "folders" is here:

[Writing IAM policies: Grant access to user-specific folders in an Amazon S3 bucket](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke)

Take a look at the 3rd block of the example:

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","home/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/David/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/David/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```